# IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12 , Ctrl+space function

Tags: java, netbeans, ide, intellij-idea, comparison

I recently, download and use IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12, Just for experience and it's amazing Dracula theme!

Now, I feel that my main problem is about `Ctrl+Space` function.

Previously i used Netbeans, Lets say by a example:

In netBeans, When you write `sy` and enter `Ctrl+Space` , it show `System` to you,

But

In IntelliJ IDEA ,When you write `sy` and enter `Ctrl+Space`, It does not show `System` to you

Thus

You should write `Sy` and enter `Ctrl+Space` to show `System` to you.

Is there any solution to solve this wasting time problem?

I use IDE for java SE apps, and swing and JDBC and ... topics

Which is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the **Case sensitive completion** to `None`:

[image: none]

Comment: I want to add JDBC library, How do it?

Comment: Refer to http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html.

Comment: Ok, Is `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12` free for ultimate time?

Comment: Yes, it's free and open source.

Comment: Nice, I think that it's more intelligent and faster that `NetBeans` for my purpose

Comment: I can not find how add MySql library to my project!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34657/discussion-between-crazycoder-and-sajjad)

Comment: Excuse me, How to large the font of code? I try it, But the menus font Was larger!

Comment: Settings | Editor | Colors & Fonts, Font. Use Save As first as you can't modify the default scheme, then change the size.

Comment: Hi, I need `DbUtils` but `IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 12` not found it, Should i download it or its build in?

Comment: @Sajjad see http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html

Comment: I see it, But it don't refer to `DbUtils` in database tools section.

Comment: If you are referring to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbutils/, download it and add the jar to the [module dependencies](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-module-dependencies-and-libraries.html).

Comment: Is adding this Jar similar to previous MySql Jar that i done it?

Comment: Yes. Please create separate SO questions for every problem you have. It's not recommended to ask lots of different questions in one or in the comments to the completely irrelevant answer. Think about other users who will have to dig through this to find the answer.

Comment: Please see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19212867/reload-changed-classes-warning-window-appear-when-run-my-program