# Reload Changed Classes Warning window appear when run my program

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide, jvm

Recently i see this warning in my IDE (intelliJ IDEA) When i want to run my program (Swing application) :

[image]

How can Fix this Problem?

Comment: What JDK version/vendor do you use to build and run your code?

Comment: @CrazyCoder I use `jdk1.7.0_11` .

Comment: Do you use JRebel or other JVM agents?

Comment: Yes, Recently i install JRebel on IDE

Comment: @CrazyCoder Another question, I want to migrate to linux , How can i download intelliJ IDEA linux version?

Comment: Which linux version is better for me?

Comment: Please do not ask several questions within one on StackOverflow. You can download IDEA for different platforms at http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/index.html .

Comment: I'd try Ubuntu 13.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This message is related to JRebel, you can use `Do not show this dialog in the future` option or uninstall JRebel.

Comment: Is it better to use JRebel? Or not? How JRebel can fix code problems?

Comment: It depends on your requirements. You can address this question to JRebel support.